# How to handle onclick javascript event in R website scraping

Tags: javascript, php, r, web-scraping, web

I have this program to web scrape one of the website and works fine for the current year data. But for the previous year data, they have this year drop down, which allows you to select the year for which data needs to be seen but the problem is that it doesn't change the year.
I noticed that they have this `onclick="javascript:return post_chg_year` function at the start of the code, which i believe doing the trick.

Now question is, how can I invoke this function in my code, to reflect the same year change.

Website Code:

```
<select name="keystat_yrc" id="keystat_yrc">
<option value=''>Select</option><option value='2018' >2018</option><option value='2017' >2017</option><option value='2016' >2016</option> …</select>
<img src="goBut3.gif" border="0" onclick="javascript:return post_chg_year('keystats');" align="absmiddle">
<a href="#" class="btnNext" rel="1"></a></h2>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Year<br>Ended</th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/equity' target='data_bank'>Equity<br><font size='1'>(Rs Cr)</font></a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/bv' target='data_bank'>BV</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th>Face<br>Value</th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/dividend' target='data_bank'>Dividend</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/prom-holding' target='data_bank'>Promoters<br>Holding</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/ronw' target='data_bank'>RONW</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/roce' target='data_bank'>ROCE</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/dte' target='data_bank'>Debt to Equity</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th><a href='/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/keystats/mktcap-sto' target='data_bank'>Market Cap/Sales</a> <span class='ar'></span></th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
```

My R Code:

```
SectorList <- read.csv("/SectorList.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")
SectorList <- as.data.frame(SectorList)
n <- 112

for (n in 1:n) {
Sector_Name <- as.character(SectorList[n,1])
SectorID <- as.character(SectorList[n,2])

aUrl <- paste0("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/",SectorID,"/1/keystats/equity")
bUrl <- paste0("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/",SectorID,"/1/annual/equity")
cUrl <- paste0("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/",SectorID,"/1/quarterly/equity”)
dUrl <- paste0("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/",SectorID,"/1/mkt-data/equity")


#Key Stats Gathering
acon <- getURL(aUrl, ssl.verifyhost=FALSE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
awebpage <- read_html(acon)

a <- awebpage %>%
html_nodes("table.cntTbls_lrg") %>%
html_nodes("td") %>%
html_text() %>%
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",.)

if(length(a)==0){
next
}
```

.
.
.
.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a complete url we can visit

Comment: here is the webpage, when you expand 4 columns you will see year dropdown on top of table...https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers.html

Comment: I had a good attempt, but couldn't find a way. I can see [here](https://stat.moneycontrol.co.in/mcjs/stocks/databank.js) a function called `post_chg_year` which appears to construct a url along the lines of `"/stocks/data-bank/"+disp_call_type+"/"+url_sel_subsector+"/"+call_type+"/"+tab+"/name"`. I tried to reconstruct this by filling in the parameters as best I can (I am no javascript expert or php expert) but I couldn't get it working. Here's my best attempt (and it doesn't seem to work) `https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers/1/annual/annual_yrc`

Comment: thanks for trying .. i was hoping to get some guidance from someone who understands little bit of java/html/php

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/data-bank/standalone/auto-2-3-wheelers.html"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
Sys.sleep(5)

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

web_Obj_Dropdown <- doc$getElementByID("chg_sector")
web_Obj_Dropdown[["Value"]] <- "aluminium"

web_Obj_Go <- doc$querySelector("#databank_nav_frm > div > div:nth-child(2) > input[type=image]")
web_Obj_Go$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)

html_Content <- doc$documentElement()$innerHtml()
read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  X1   
  <lgl>
1 NA   

[[2]]
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   `Key Stats` `Key Stats`   `Key Stats`
   <chr>       <chr>         <chr>      
 1 YearEnded   Equity(Rs Cr) BV         
 2 Mar'22      54.94         2.71       
 3 Mar'22      18.52         9.75       
 4 Mar'22      8.00          7.41       
 5 Mar'22      10.02         9.82       
 6 Mar'22      5.27          12.96      
 7 Mar'22      10.20         15.05      
 8 Mar'22      6.30          99.44      
 9 Mar'22      13.52         62.40      
10 Mar'22      6.55          17.75      
11 Mar'22      918.32        68.36      
12 Mar'20      58.72         -0.24      
13 Mar'22      9.10          267.73     
14 Mar'22      19.13         18.40      
15 Mar'22      7.37          -94.54     

[[3]]
# A tibble: 15 x 11
   Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420~1 Key S~2 Key S~3 Key S~4 Key S~5 Key S~6 Key S~7 Key S~8 Key S~9 Key S~* Key S~*
   <chr>                                                                             <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>  
 1 YearEnded                                                                         Equity~ BV      FaceVa~ Divide~ Promot~ RONW    ROCE    Debt t~ Market~ NA     
 2 Mar'22                                                                            54.94   2.71    10      -       33.77%  -1.12%  -0.91%  0.21    -       NA     
 3 Mar'22                                                                            18.52   9.75    10      -       73.59%  -7.06%  -1.74%  3.05    41.01   NA     
 4 Mar'22                                                                            8.00    7.41    1       -       52.04%  10.41%  15.71%  0.75    0.28    NA     
 5 Mar'22                                                                            10.02   9.82    10      -       72.85%  -0.12%  -0.07%  0.53    0.44    NA     
 6 Mar'22                                                                            5.27    12.96   10      -       60.50%  7.57%   7.60%   0.00    25.18   NA     
 7 Mar'22                                                                            10.20   15.05   10      -       68.63%  22.20%  24.14%  0.43    4.71    NA     
 8 Mar'22                                                                            6.30    99.44   10      -       62.12%  -1.23%  1.75%   0.30    1.01    NA     
 9 Mar'22                                                                            13.52   62.40   10      10%     65.32%  26.04%  23.20%  0.77    0.37    NA     
10 Mar'22                                                                            6.55    17.75   1       -       64.73%  6.41%   9.00%   1.09    0.32    NA     
11 Mar'22                                                                            918.32  68.36   5       130%    56.77%  23.51%  31.63%  0.00    0.89    NA     
12 Mar'20                                                                            58.72   -0.24   10      -       2.15%   31.14%  663.13% 0.00    -       NA     
13 Mar'22                                                                            9.10    267.73  10      20%     57.81%  19.12%  13.23%  1.07    0.71    NA     
14 Mar'22                                                                            19.13   18.40   10      -       56.53%  6.30%   5.76%   0.68    0.42    NA     
15 Mar'22                                                                            7.37    -94.54  10      -       63.02%  13.79%  -10.28% 0.00    0.05    NA     
# ... with abbreviated variable names
#   1: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`,
#   2: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`,
#   3: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`,
#   4: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`,
#   5: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`,
#   6: `Key Stats   \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect20222021202020192018201720162015201420132012201120102009200820072006200520042003200220012000`, ...

[[4]]
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   Annual    Annual       Annual    
   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>     
 1 YearEnded Sales(Rs Cr) Sales% Chg
 2 Mar'22    -            -         
 3 Mar'22    0.14         -95.62%   
 4 Mar'22    322.46       72.13%    
 5 Mar'22    4.09         -83.16%   
 6 Mar'22    0.43         -9.70%    
 7 Mar'22    84.56        46.44%    
 8 Mar'22    23.58        -72.76%   
 9 Mar'22    572.29       42.05%    
10 Mar'22    436.22       60.59%    
11 Mar'22    14,180.81    58.34%    
12 Mar'20    -            -         
13 Mar'22    394.54       56.78%    
14 Mar'22    90.69        10.11%    
15 Mar'22    128.94       57.71%
```